# Maximum Changes that don't Break the Build

Tags: asymptotics, minimum-cuts

Let's say I have a set of changes, e.g. replacing `foo` with `bar` in a codebase, how do I programmatically discover the largest set of replacements that will not break my tests. let's assume that the call-sites are independent.

I can come up with a binary-search-like algorithm which would be worst case `O(n)` time. Proposed binary-search-like algorithm:

```
possible_changes = Set(Range(0, n - 1)) // all callsites
working_changes = Set()

while (possible_changes non empty) {
  for (range in possible_changes) {
    remove the range from possible_changes

    if (range causes failures) {
      if (range size == 1) {
        // forget the range
      } else {
        left, right = split the range
        if (range size == 2) {
          if (left does not cause failure) {
            add left to working_changes
            // forget right
          } else if (right does not cause failure) {
            add right to working changes
          }
        } else {
          add left to possible_changes
          add right to possible_changes
        }
      }
    } else {
      add range to working_changes
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a **faster way**, besides above to find all changes that would work?

Comment: "how do I programmatically discover the largest set of replacements that will not break my tests" To develop an efficient algorithm, it is important to model the problem appropriately. Source code is not a very good model to analyze a computer program. It seems your code is assuming some model (a control-flow graph?), it would be helpful if you make your model explicit. "let's assume that the call-sites are independent." It would also be useful to explicitly state what a "call-site" is in this model, and what independence means here.

Comment: You also appear to be asking two things of your algorithm: 1. find _some_ set of replacements with maximum cardinality. 2. find _all_ sets of replacements with maximum cardinality. Please clarify which of these options you actually want.

Comment: I wrote `let's assume that the call-sites are independent` in the original question. By that I meant that if replacing call site `a` and `b` each succeed in isolation, then one can assume replacing both is successful also.

Code may not be the best way to model this, but it's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're trying to solve is undecidable, since you can't tell if any of the changes makes the program go into an infinite loop.

Comment: let's assume that the call-sites are independent - meaning replacing call site `a` and `b` succeeding separately means replacing both is successful also

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the problem is NP-hard, in the worst case.  If you have $n$ candidate replacements, you might have to try all $2^n$ combinations of replacements.

Fortunately, in practice, there are often circumstances where you can find a reasonable solution more efficiently, because many call sites are at least somewhat independent.  Then it becomes an optimization problem: given a boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, find $x$ of largest Hamming weight such that $f(x)=1$.  (Here the bit-string $x$ indicates which of the replacements are applied, and $f(x)$ represents whether the program passes all your tests.)

There are many possible approaches.  One standard algorithm is to use [delta debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_debugging) or some other [bisection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_(software_engineering)).  Normally, these algorithms are phrased in terms of finding the *smallest* set of changes that makes the code work; in your case, you want to find the *largest* set of changes that makes the code work, but that is isomorphic (instead of choosing which candidate changes to apply, you can choosing which to avoid applying).  These algorithms are easy to implement and fairly efficient in practice.

This assumes that, given a combination of candidate changes, you can tell whether it passes all of your tests in a finite amount of time.  In theory, as David Richerby explains, you can't, because you can't tell whether the program has entered an infinite loop (and thus doesn't pass the tests) or whether the program is just taking a really long time (and will eventually pass the tests).  In practice, we bypass that difficulty by placing a time limit, and if the program doesn't terminate within that time, we consider it to have failed the tests.